# How to loop over wp_get_themes() and create an array of themes name

Tags: themes, php

So wp_get_themes() returns an array of objects :

```
Array
(
    [WpAngular] => WP_Theme Object
        (
            [update] => 
            [theme_root:WP_Theme:private] => /home/love/Web/web/app/themes
            [headers:WP_Theme:private] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => WpAngular
                    [ThemeURI] => http://www.someurl.com
                    [Description] => blak blak.
                    [Author] => Joy division
                    [AuthorURI] => http://www.someurl.com
                    [Version] => 6.0
                    [Template] => 
                    [Status] => 
                    [Tags] => WordPress
                    [TextDomain] => 
                    [DomainPath] => 
                )

            [headers_sanitized:WP_Theme:private] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => WpAngular
                )

            [name_translated:WP_Theme:private] => 
            [errors:WP_Theme:private] => 
            [stylesheet:WP_Theme:private] => Angular-Wordpress
            [template:WP_Theme:private] => Angular-Wordpress
            [parent:WP_Theme:private] => 
            [theme_root_uri:WP_Theme:private] => 
            [textdomain_loaded:WP_Theme:private] => 
            [cache_hash:WP_Theme:private] => 03dc86f794762ab23bab120e9b121326
        )

    [Some Theme] => WP_Theme Object
        (
            [update] => 
            [theme_root:WP_Theme:private] => /home/love6/Web/web/app/themes
            [headers:WP_Theme:private] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Some Theme
                    [ThemeURI] => http://www.someurl.com
                    [Description] => Blak Blak.
                    [Author] => Some dude
                    [AuthorURI] => http://www.someurl.com
                    [Version] => 2.0
                    [Template] => 
                    [Status] => 
                    [Tags] => 
                    [TextDomain] => 
                    [DomainPath] => 
                )

            [headers_sanitized:WP_Theme:private] => Array
                (
                    [Name] => Some Theme
                )

            [name_translated:WP_Theme:private] => 
            [errors:WP_Theme:private] => 
            [stylesheet:WP_Theme:private] => some-theme
            [template:WP_Theme:private] => some-theme
            [parent:WP_Theme:private] => 
            [theme_root_uri:WP_Theme:private] => 
            [textdomain_loaded:WP_Theme:private] => 
            [cache_hash:WP_Theme:private] => a1a2613543a81b28b06ac802adb785fc
        )
)
```

I'm trying to build function that returns an array of the theme names from the objects.

```
function my_get_allowed_themes() {



        $theme_args = array( 'errors' => false , 'allowed' => 'site' );

        $allowed_themes = wp_get_themes($theme_args);

        $allowed_themes = null;

        $demos = array();

        $allowed_theme_names = array();

         // loop over themes and grab the theme name
         foreach ( $allowed_themes as $allowed_theme ) {

               $allowed_theme_names[] = $allowed_theme['Name'];


          }

          return $allowed_theme_names;    

    }
```

However, this is just returning an empty array. What am I missing?

Comment: Use `$allowed_theme->name`, the `__get()` method will return the proper value.

Comment: @toscho, when I use: $allowed_theme->name;  I just get an output of what looks like an array of php methods. Weird. What do you mean by __get()?

Comment: Please add the code and the output to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct the `wp_get_themes()` function has most of the information inaccessible to the public which requires you to pull the info out using the `$theme->get( 'Name' );` format. You can build a simple array like so.

```
// Build new empty Array to store the themes
$themes = array();

// Loads theme data
$all_themes = wp_get_themes();

// Loads theme names into themes array
foreach ($all_themes as $theme) {
  $themes[] = $theme->get('Name');
}

// Prints the theme names
print_r( $themes );
```

Which will output

```
Array (
  [0] => Anchor Blank
  [1] => Swell - Anchor Hosting
  [2] => Swell
)
```

Taking this one step future you can build an array with all of the theme data like so.

```
// Build new empty Array to store the themes
$themes = array();

// Loads theme data
$all_themes = wp_get_themes();

// Build theme data manually
foreach ($all_themes as $theme) {
  $themes{ $theme->stylesheet } = array(
    'Name' => $theme->get('Name'),
    'Description' => $theme->get('Description'),
    'Author' => $theme->get('Author'),
    'AuthorURI' => $theme->get('AuthorURI'),
    'Version' => $theme->get('Version'),
    'Template' => $theme->get('Template'),
    'Status' => $theme->get('Status'),
    'Tags' => $theme->get('Tags'),
    'TextDomain' => $theme->get('TextDomain'),
    'DomainPath' => $theme->get('DomainPath')
  );
}

// Prints the themes
print_r( $themes );
```

This will output an array which looks like the following

```
Array (
[anchor-blank] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Anchor Blank
        [Description] => Anchor Hosting blank theme
        [Author] => Anchor Hosting
        [AuthorURI] => https://anchor.host
        [Version] => 1.1
        [Template] =>
        [Status] => publish
        [Tags] => Array
            (
            )

        [TextDomain] => anchor-blank
        [DomainPath] => /languages/
    )

[swell-anchorhost] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Swell - Anchor Hosting
        [Description] => Child theme for Anchor Hosting
        [Author] => Anchor Hosting
        [AuthorURI] => https://anchor.host
        [Version] => 1.1.0
        [Template] => swell
        [Status] => publish
        [Tags] => Array
            (
            )

        [TextDomain] => swell
        [DomainPath] => /languages/
    )

[swell] => Array
    (
        [Name] => Swell
        [Description] => Swell is a one-column, typography-focused, video Wordpress theme.
        [Author] => ThemeTrust.com
        [AuthorURI] => http://themetrust.com
        [Version] => 1.2.6
        [Template] =>
        [Status] => publish
        [Tags] => Array
            (
            )

        [TextDomain] => swell
        [DomainPath] => /languages/
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access `WP_Theme` object like below

```
 $theme = wp_get_theme();
 $name = $theme->{'Name'};
```

or

```
$theme->get( 'Name' );
```

Answer (score -2):

Here theme names that are displayed from `wp_get_themes()` stores private information, as you can see

`[headers:WP_Theme:private]`

So you can't access the private variable directly.
For accessing the private variable you need to inherit the parent class.

## Update

```
$get_theme = wp_get_themes();
$all_theme = array_keys( $get_theme ) );
print_r( $all_theme );  //will return all theme
```

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: This doesn't work. I still get an empty array.